# Displaying an array in multiple columns using listbox using tkinter

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, listbox

I have a list whose values are unrelated to each other and I'm going to display it using Tkinter Listbox, but all the data are displayed in one column with a scroller, how can I display them in multiple columns like the picture?

[the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he837.png)

Comment: # No Clue Response
Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Begin [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html). Don't use Tkinter if you don't have to

Comment: @itprorh66 I've edited it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a [basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_) on tkinter. There you will be teached about events and event objects. Also look up in a [good documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) To give you an idea of the power by events, see below.

```
import tkinter as tk

def highlight(event):
    widget = event.widget
    if str(event.type) == 'Enter':
        widget.config(bg='blue')
    elif str(event.type) == 'Leave':
        widget.config(bg='#f0f0f0')

lng = ['Arabic','Bosnian','German','English']

root = tk.Tk()
for i in lng:
    l = tk.Label(root,text=i)
    l.pack(fill='x')
    l.bind('<Enter>', highlight)
    l.bind('<Leave>',highlight)
```

Comment: I will, thank you :)